# Alert if mandatory textbox is empty

Tags: jquery, html

I have to check if all mandatory fields are filled in before I send them to database. This is done trough column `IDMandatory`. If the field is mandatory then value of this column is `True` if not it is `False`.
Here's a code snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/m8dLwf9z/30/

I have a problem with this snippet, it's not working properly(the 'else' part).
It needs to fire on button click when any mandatory textbox is left unfilled.
And when all mandatory textbox's are filled it should activate the "Activate the ajax" alert.
I have ajax code that's ready and working that's needs to go when first condition is meet.

```
$(function() {
  $(".IDMandatory").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
      $(el).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("required", true);
    }
  });

  $("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    var ok = true;
    $("[required]").each(function() {
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid black"); // reset

      if (!$(this).val()) {
        ok = false;
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
      }
     else {
         alert("Fill in remaining fields!");
         ok = false;  // Alert if mandatory fields are left unfilled
      }

    });
    if (ok) {
      alert('Activate the AJAX!'); // When everything if filled activate ajax code
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone help me with this code ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to move your `else` condition to bottom where you checking `ok`, see snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".IDMandatory").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($(el).text().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
      $(el).closest("tr").find("input,select").prop("required", true);
    }
  });

  $("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    var ok = true;
    $("[required]").each(function() {
      $(this).css("border", "1px solid black"); // reset

      if (!$(this).val()) {
        ok = false;
        $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
      }
       
    });
    if (ok) {
      alert('Activate the AJAX!');
    } else {
      alert("Fill in the remaining mandatory fields!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.IDKarakteristike
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike" style="color:#333333;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#507CD1;font-weight:bold;">
    <th scope="col">Characteristic</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_0" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GRRF Adress</span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_0" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">1</span>

    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_LabelMan_0" class="IDMandatory" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;display: none;">True</span>


    </td>
    <td>



      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl02$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="4" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_0" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_1" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GFP Wear</span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_1" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">2</span>

    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_LabelMan_1" class="IDMandatory" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;display: none;">True</span>


    </td>
    <td>



      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl03$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="6" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_1" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_2" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">FVD Weight </span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_2" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">3</span>

    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_LabelMan_2" class="IDMandatory" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;display: none;">True</span>


    </td>
    <td>



      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl04$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="8" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_2" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
    <td>
      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_3" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">GVDtreatment
</span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_3" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">5</span>

    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_LabelMan_3" class="IDMandatory" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;display: none;">False</span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <select name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl05$ddlOpis" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_3" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:35px;width:161px;">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Lacquer
</option>
    <option value="2"> Hardwax Oil
</option>
    <option value="3">Lacquer
</option>
    <option value="4">Proteco 
</option>
    <option value="5">e Treatment</option>

   </select>



    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
    <td>
      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Karakteristike_4" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">FVF  hierarchy
</span>


    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_Label_4" class="IDKarakteristike" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;">9</span>

    </td>
    <td>

      <span id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_LabelMan_4" class="IDMandatory" margin-Left="100px" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;display: none;">False</span>


    </td>
    <td>



      <input name="ctl00$MainContent$gvKarakteristike$ctl06$txtBoxOpis" type="text" maxlength="60" id="MainContent_gvKarakteristike_txtBoxOpis_4" margin-Left="100px" style="font-family:Georgia;height:30px;width:150px;" />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="button" class="button" id="myButton" value="Save" />

<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$(function() {
     $(".IDMandatory").each(function(i, el) {
if ($(el).text().toUpperCase() === "TRUE") {
  $(el).parents("tr").find("input,select").attr("required", true);
}
});

$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
var ok = true;
$("[required]").each(function() {
  $(this).css("border", "1px solid black"); // reset

  if (!$(this).val()) {
    ok = false;
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
  }

});
if (ok) {
  alert('Activate the AJAX!');
} else {
    alert("Fill in the remaining mandatory fields!");
}
});
});
```